# How many solution for the equation $x+y=m+6$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality

$$ x+ y = m + 6 $$
$$ 1 \le x,y \le 6 $$

My calculations are definitely wrong.

I'm trying to solve the following equation instead:

$$ w_1+ w_2 = m + 4 $$
$$ w_1=x-1, w_2=y-2$$
$$ 0 \le w_1,w_2 \le 5 $$

- I'm having a hard time to understand why the amount of solutions for the above equation is equal to the number of solutions for the first one.

Thirdly, to solve the above, I will calculated how many solutions for:

$$ w_1+ w_2 = m + 4 $$
$$ 6 \le w_1 (or) 6 \le w_2 $$

To calculate how many solutions for the above, I will calculate how many solutions for:

$$ w_1+ w_2 = m + 4 $$
$$ 0 \le w_1,w_2 $$

Which is $ \binom{m+5}{m+4} = m+5$. I solved it by ordering $(m+4)$ `a` and $1$ `b` in a line.

and how many solutions for:

$$ z_1+ w_2 = m - 2,w_1+ z_2 = m - 2,z_1+ z_2 = m - 8 $$
$$ z_1=w_1-6, z_2=w_2-6 $$
$$ 6 \le z_1,z_2,0 \le w_1,w_2 $$

The amount of solutions for $ z_1+ w_2 = m - 2 $ is $ m-1 $.
The amount of solutions for $ w_1+ z_2 = m - 2 $ is $ m-1 $.
The amount of solutions for $ z_1+ z_2  = m - 8 $ is $ m-7 $.

So the amount of solutions for $ w_1+ w_2 = m + 4 $ with the restrication of $ 6 \le w_1 or 6 \le w_2 $ is: (by the *Inclusion–exclusion principle*)

$$ m-1 + m-1 - (m-7) = m+5 $$

**As you can notice, I'm definitely wrong because the amount of solutions to the same equation with and without restrictions is the same.**

The final result for $ x+ y = m + 6 $ is $ 0 $ **which is absolutly wrong**.

Comment: Use "\le" for $\le$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

You mean to say $x\ge 1$,$y\le 6$ and $0\le m\le 5$

Then try breaking question into parts like $$x+y=6$$ in this case $m=0$ . Hence by star and bars method we get answer for this case as $6$.

Then try finding solutions for $m=1$ i.e. $$x+y=7$$ again by star and bars method we get solution as $7$ for this case.

Similarly continue for $m=2,3,4,5$ and sum up the result to get final answer.

Comment: $1<=x,y<=6$ . Are we on the same page?

Comment: @StavAlfi Yes of course but the only difference is that while applying star and bars there needs to be taken a precaution about restrictions on x, y which will be more prominent as we go from m=2 to m=5

Comment: Can you please refer to my mistake in my calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Do u know that no. of "positive integer" solutions of the equation $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=m$ where $x_i$'s & $m$ is positive integer is $\binom{m-1}{n-1}$ 
So using this putting each $m$ from 0 to 5 , u get the number of solution and then sum it for total solution

Comment: You did not take account the restrictions on x, y. Remember that $x\ge 1$ and $y\le 6$

Comment: @Manthanein I guess he account cases $x \ge 1$ and $y \le 6$
Because $\binom{m-1}{n-1}$ works for natural solutions

Comment: @Manthanein so I guess the answer is $\sum_{m=0}^{6} \binom{m+5}{1} = 5+6+7+8+9+10+11=56$

Comment: @openspace Nope that's not the answer.  For $m=2$ solution is 7, while for $m=1$ is also 7. This is because the method he used don't account for $y\le 6$. For example in $m=0$ his method finds answer is 5 while answer is 6

Comment: Why 6? (1,5), (2,4), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1) , there are 5 pairs

Comment: @openspace what about (6,0). I know (0,6) is not allowed but (6,0) can be included

Comment: @Manthanein $1 \le x,y \le 6$

Comment: @openspace so $x=6\ge 1$ and $y=0\le 6$ is also a solution

Comment: @Manthanein I guess both of them should be more than one and less then zero. OP should mention this part

Comment: @openspace yeah because OP didn't say $x, y$ are natural numbers but it's okay leave

Answer (score 1):

So u have to subtract the case when $y\geq 7$ .

Now let, $x+y=n$ where $x\geq 1$ and $y\geq 7$ 
now consider $x'=x-1\geq 0$ and $y'=x-7\geq 0$
so this gives $x'+y'=n-8$ so non-negative solution for this is $\binom{n-7}{1}$. 
This is it u have subtract each step. Let me Know when you finished.

Comment: this is what I have done..... What is my mistake?

Comment: Actually I didn't see your solution. It's totally fine dude

Answer (score 0):

Okay if you consider **positive** solutions , then answer should be $\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{5}\binom{m+5}{1}=45$

If you consider **non-negative** solutions , then number of solutions for some *m* is $\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}$, so there will be $\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{5}\binom{m+7}{1} = 57$

Comment: I don't know what is your definition of `natural` but I explicitly specified the range of every variable. Can you please refer to my mistake instead of giving a final solution?

Comment: @StavAlfi edited

Comment: Agian, I explicitly specified the possible range for every variable. $ 1<=x,y <= 6$ and $ 0<=m<=5 $

Comment: @StavAlfi the question is : both of $x,y$ more than $1$ and less than $6$ ?

Comment: Sory, I didn't understand what are you asking.

Comment: @StavAlfi do you consider pairs $(0,6)$ and $(6,0)$ for $m = 0$?

Comment: no, because $1 <=x,y $

Comment: @StavAlfi then the first one is correct.

Comment: I'm sure you are currect :) Can you please specify what is my mistake in my calculation?